# Connected to my android device using ADB but not able to use ls command, it says permission denied

Tags: android, adb

I connected to my android device (stock android, 10) using ADB on ubuntu, now when I go to /data/ and do ls, it says permission denied.

Why? How to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to ROOT device

Answer (score 2):

Once you enter the ADB shell(`adb -s your_ip:5555 shell`), you can use `run-as com.example.app` to access the data folder of a specific application.

Replace "com.example.app" with your package name

Answer (score 0):

The user id used in adb shell sessions is different from the one that created the `data` folder (and subfolders). The permissions' set are `drwxrwx--x` that means `--x` for everyone, i.e., execute only.

What you can do is to go into the different folders using `cd` command or using Android Studio's Device File Explorer, more info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer).